# What is the spell Vierna uses in Book One of the Legacy of the Drow (pg 150) to create webbing that cannot be cut by any weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, lore, content-identification

In the legacy of the drow, Drizzt's sister Vierna used a wand to create a web (obviously a create web spell), then she "produced a packet of fine dust, and, beginning a second chang she sprinkled it over the web. Immediately the strands thickend and took on a black & silvery luster. Then the shine faded and the warmth of the enchantment's energy cooled to room temperature.." She then declares that "No weapon can cut the strands."

Side note- the web also holds fast anything that touches it.

I am trying to homebrew some armor and am wondering what 5e spell would equate to this enchantment?  I thought Hardening came closest, but the way it is described it would be insufficient to make spider webs impenetrable.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: The dust sounds like a magic item more than a spell, to me. But in any event, _Legacy of the Drow_ was from 1992—what makes you think that any 5e material was involved in this process? AD&D 2e was current then, and has vastly more content than 5e does—and it’s not as though Salvatore limited himself to canonical D&D abilities in the first place. I suspect this question has no answer, but if it does, limiting yourself to 5e material seems likely to risk not finding it.

Comment: I voted to close because of the wrong edition tag, and the "don't guess the system" rule this site follows would prevent me from changing it. If you edit to have the adnd-2e tag, I'll vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

The wand of Viscid Globs is in a 2nd edition book called the *Drow of the Underdark*.

*Stoneskin* was then applied after.

Note 1: In 2nd edition, *stoneskin* was a touch spell, and thus could affect objects

Note 2:  Back in the day(2e) terms were more vague. So "creature" might also apply to objects or characters or anything the DM wanted.  It was a different and less specific time.

Source 2e *Player's Handbook* page 163

> #### Stoneskin (S M V)
>
> - Spell Level 4
> - Class Wizard
> - School Alteration
> - Range Touch
> - Casting Time 1
> - Duration Special
> - Save None
> - Requirements Somatic, Material, Verbal,
> - Materials granite and diamond dust
>
> When this spell is cast, the affected creature gains a virtual immunity to any attack by cut, blow, projectile, or the like. Even a *sword of sharpness* cannot affect a creature protected by *stoneskin*, nor can a rock hurled by a giant, a snake's strike, etc.
> However, magical attacks from such spells as *fireball*, *magic missile*, *lightning bolt*, and so forth have their normal effects.
>
> The spell's effects are not cumulative with multiple castings.
>
> The spell blocks 1d4 attacks, plus one attack per two levels of experience the caster has achieved. This limit applies regardless of attack rolls and regardless of whether the attack was physical or magical.
>
> The material components of the spell are granite and diamond dust sprinkled on the recipient's skin.

Adamantine Armor might work for your purposes.

Comment: The *Google* says the original quotation is *From a pouch she produced a packet of fine dust, and, beginning a second chant​, she sprinkled it over the web.* Is there a *wand of viscid globes* that can bring forth a web? The part about the *stoneskin* spell is interesting, though.

Comment: It might help to back up “thus could affect objects” a little bit more—I’m not familiar enough with 2e to say if that’s true or false, so I feel that I can’t upvote the answer. Likewise, at least in editions of D&D I am familiar with, the effect of a spell or magic wand (be it *web* or *viscid globs*) would not usually qualify as an “object” per se, and so it would be necessary that *stoneskin* (or touch spells in general) could be applied to magic effects too (but again, that might be different in 2e).

Comment: Clerics could not cast web in 2e so she used the wand which does cast web.   Then she cast stone skin.   I will add details about the 2e stoneskin spell

Comment: I mean, “it could work if the DM let it” kind of applies to anything and everything D&D; is there any particular statement in 2e that an object or spell effect could be considered a “creature” for the purposes of a spell? The fact that *stoneskin* refers to the “skin” of the creature kind of leads me to suspect that this would not generally have been considered a kosher combination... Also, 1d4 attacks is a lot less than the kind of “we won’t have to worry about this anymore” certainty that Vierna displayed.

Comment: He didn't want me to quote him, but the author of the book said "he was taking liberties" with the spell, but that Stoneskin was the spell he used.   Can't get much more of a direct answer than that.

Comment: @SamLacrumb That’s awesome! But unless it’s in an answer, we can’t really do much with that information. If the request was that he not be _quoted_ on it, but a paraphrase as in your comment would be acceptable, you might add that to your answer. However, if the request was more that you keep it private, I don’t really know that you can respect those wishes and also integrate it into this answer (or that you should have included it in a comment). Up to you how to handle this situation, but ultimately votes on answers only cover what’s actually in the answer.

Comment: Yeah.. I dont really want to risk upsetting the author of the books I love for votes.. so I will keep it as is.

Answer (score -1):

The spell being cast sounds somewhat like the 3.5e spell [stoneskin](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/stoneskin.htm), which allows the target creature to ignore the first 10 points of damage from weapons that aren't adamantine.  That spell requires 250gp worth of diamond dust, which might be what was in the "packet of fine dust".

The main difference between this spell and the usage you found is that the 3.5e *stoneskin* cannot be cast on a web.

Vierna's assertion that "No weapon can cut the strands" may have been partially a bluff, since saying "this spell ignores the first 10 damage you do" would have just invited the people caught in it to use their higher-damage weapons.

The 5e *stoneskin* spell was nerfed: it only grants "resistance to nonmagical damage".  I still think it is the closest you'll find to this spell.

KRyan points out that your book was using 2e rules.  The *stoneskin* spell did exist in 2e, according to a [wiki entry](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Stoneskin) I found, but I don't have the text of the spell.

Comment: I agree that that's a key difference, but I think I mentioned that (the first sentence of my second paragraph).

Comment: OK, you’re right, missed that somehow. But between that and the fact that 3.5e was written 12 years after _Legacy of the Drow_ makes this rather less than convincing to me. Was there at least a 2e version of the spell we could compare?